# AppInviteReferral is deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am following the Firebase invite tutorial from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder

A lot of code is relying on deprecated classes. Is there a alternative 'new' classes and apis.

Comment: Replaced by Firebase Invites. The class name is the same, the package is different. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/package-summary More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to take a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteReferral):

> This class was deprecated.
>
> Use [`FirebaseAppInvite`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/appinvite/FirebaseAppInvite.html), returned by
>   [`getInvitation(com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.PendingDynamicLinkData)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/appinvite/FirebaseAppInvite.html#getInvitation(com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.PendingDynamicLinkData)),
>   which holds the deep link and invitation id.

Comment: Ah. A blur of vision . Thanks for the input. I was just using android api and  there was no suggested change in the documentation of deprecated api java code. All is well . Thank you.